# Filtering list multiple times by property

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of tasks which each have a status. I need to filter them in this order:

```
status: 'overdue'
status: 'next_appointment'
status: null (ordered by soonest dueDate)
status: null (ordered by oldest createdAt no dueDate set)
```

Is there a way to apply multiple filters like this on a repeat? Would I need to create my own custom filter? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm actually trying that right now. Hopefully it will be a winner.

Comment: One problem I'm seeing by doing it in the controller is that I have specific stylings and elements for each type. Such as an <hr /> separating the different statuses. Do you know how I would account for those things if I just did it through the controller?

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, you simply need 3 ng-repeats, each using its own filter, and the last one using an orderBy.

Comment: Sounds great to me. I'm going to try that out.